# Configuring default woo commerce login with modal popup

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-gravity-forms

Good day. I was trying to configure the default woo commerce login page.

[image]

I want to add the two contents (login) and (register) to a modal popup separately. let's say if the user is not logged in and wants to register, the user will click it and inside the popup, there's a content with button named logged in and if the user will click that, the modal will automatically switch and input the credentials.

1. We tried using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/ and configured the default register account using the gravity forms. and then add the shortcode to the popup maker and it worked.
2. the problem is we can't configure the default login and add it to gravity form the same way we configured the default register form.
3. we can't fix the auto switch functions if the user clicked the modal button and wants to either register or login.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question U can also make custom popup using bootstrap it's totally customizable. Here is the example [http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/login-registration-modal#.](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/login-registration-modal#)
To use this u need to copy required bootstrap files where u want to use this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @faisal, but i was wondering if i can use the default login of the woo commerce and add it to the modal page.